# Unable to generate a shared library using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, c++17, sdl

I was trying to generate a shared library for my project using cmake, unfortunately I got this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I'm building a static library it works. This is my cmake file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(yanthra_console VERSION 0.1 DESCRIPTION "A 3d Game Engine.")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -fexceptions")
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "RelWithDebInfo;Release;Debug" CACHE STRING "Build type selections" FORCE)



set(THIRD_PARTY_DIR "../../third-party")
set(MAIN_SOURCE_DIR "../main/src")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/out)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

include_directories(${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/SDL/include)

file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_HEADERS ${MAIN_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_SOURCES ${MAIN_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)


add_library(
   yanthra
   SHARED
   ${CPP_HEADERS}
   ${CPP_SOURCES}
)

add_executable(
    yanthra_console
    ${CPP_HEADERS}
    ${CPP_SOURCES}
)

set_target_properties(
    yanthra_console 
    PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS
    "-F../Frameworks -framework SDL2 -framework OpenGL"
)


target_link_libraries(yanthra_console PRIVATE yanthra)
```

I was able to create a static library with executable.Im using Mulit Configuration to build the project.

Comment: Is the error message from when you try to build you library, or when you try to use it? I'm guessing the `add_executable` part works for you, but if you try to use `add_library` it fails?

Comment: @super yes exactly. The ```add_executable``` works perfectly fine alone as well as when using it to generate a static library. The error only appears when trying to generate a shared library. Thanks for replying.

Comment: So did you add LINK_FLAGS to your library target?

Comment: I did add it to executable target but not for the library. Which method should I use to add it ?

Comment: I got it working using set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS). Thank you @super, you are a real life saver.

Comment: You should use `set_target_properties` just like you did for `yanthra_console`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a symbol visibility issue.

By default on clang/gcc symbols are hidden.

There is a cppcon talk that talks about this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0DwB4OvDXk&list=PL4s9OdsBXD7aXhgqibbEzf8zAM5eiiENs&index=9

Basically either this library doesn't support being built as a shared library.
Or you need to enable that functionality somehow.

Or just force symbol visibility on.